# How do I highlight the current TextMate document in the project drawer?

Tags: macos, textmate, highlight

I keep forgetting where to find this in the menus.  I often open a document using (for example) Find in Project… and then want to know where it is in the project drawer (especially when it's buried deep down in the folder hierarchy.  How do I highlight the current document in the project drawer?

Comment: I know the answer, but I'll give others a chance first.

Comment: Why did you make up a question you already knew the answer to? Doesn't make much sense to me. If you wanted to answer the question, so someone having it will already find the answer: I don't think thats a good idea. First, this is a real easy question. Second, if we did so with all possible questions available, we would quickly run out of interesting questions, which are buried by questions like this one.

Comment: Jeff and Joel have encouraged creating a question and providing the answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions.  I agree with them that this is one good way to get canonical questions and answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### TexMate 1

It's "hiding" in the File menu as "Reveal in Project" (with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>).

### TextMate 2

It's "hiding" in the Go menu as "Current Document" (with the keyboard shortcut <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>).