# Automatically reveal current file in TextMate project drawer

Tags: textmate

There is a [key chord to highlight the current document in the project drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393334/how-do-i-highlight-the-current-textmate-document-in-the-project-drawer) but I want it to happen **automatically**.

Is there any way to make TextMate reveal files automatically by expanding the parent hierarchy whenever I switch documents? If possible, I'd also like to collapse that hierarchy to its prior state when the file loses focus.

(For background, as a point of comparison: In Eclipse I can [link the Navigator with the currently active editor](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_link_the_Navigator_with_the_currently_active_editor%3F) to always show the currently edited file in the hierarchy of files. It does highlight the file if it's visible in the project drawer, but I want it to reveal files hidden in collapsed folders. )

Comment: My version of Textmate (Version 1.5.10 (1623)) highlights the current file in the drawer automatically. If, however, the location of the file is in a collapsed folder, it does not expand to reveal the file. Is that the behavior you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, I want it to expand folders in order to show the highlighted file. I'd also like it to collapse folders that it expanded when the file loses focus. I'll update my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TextMate can't do this natively but it can be added with a plugin.

[Project+](http://ciaranwal.sh/projectplus) does it already.

[Missing Drawer](https://github.com/jezdez/textmate-missingdrawer) may have [added the feature](https://github.com/jezdez/textmate-missingdrawer/issues/44) by the time you read this.

Comment: I installed Missing Drawer and it has implemented this to a satisfactory degree. The only complaint I have against it is that the background color it uses to highlight the filename is a very faint gray.  But it works anyways on Mac OS X 10.9

Answer (score 32):

You can do this by using the combinations Ctrl+Command+R

Comment: Well, that's the key chord I was referring to in the link above. My question is how to have that happen automatically whenever I change files.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same question. Didn't find an answer googling and emailed their support.

`Preferences → Projects, Keep current document selected`

should do it on TextMate 2.